# How to change array index to start from 1?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

How can I change my array's indices to start from 1 instead of 0. I am trying to fetch news from a site (JSON) and after parsing it:

```
@news = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://api.site.com/news?format=json')))
```

But to see the individual news title, I have to do `@news["items"][0]` for the first link's title. Is it possible to change that behavior so when I do `@news["items"][1]` it shows me the first link's title?

Comment: Did I miss something, what's the problem with zero-based arrays?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It was for a voice application, so when user enters 1 it plays the title for the first link. Now, 0 is pressed for the first link

Comment: Every sane language I've tried uses zero-based array access. You better get used to it (or you can switch to VB) :)

Comment: Well, you can intercept and interpret that user input, can't you?

Comment: Bing! Yes, I subtracted 1 from user's input and now it works! Thank you man!

Comment: I'm going to post this as an answer, so that you can give me some points :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev FWIW Lua uses 1-based array access. ([Not that I like it.](http://phrogz.net/aesthetic-argument-for-0-based-indices))

Comment: @Phrogz: I didn't try Lua yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should intercept user input and adjust entered value to map to a correct array element. In general, you should always validate user input and check if it makes sense.